# What version of Unity will be used in 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04

As the question goes, at the end, what version of Unity will be used in 12.04 for the final release. Will it keep on with the 4.x or will it use 5.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Precise Pangoline, they have already upgraded the Unity package at the 5.6 for Unity (as stated [here in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity)) and Unity-2D (as stated [here in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity-2d))..besides, in the 5.4 version of Unity, they released the new feature, HUD, as explained by Mark Shuttleworth (you can read it [here](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/Unity/HUD)).

Comment: This post is already somewhat outdated; Unity in Precise is currently at 5.6, and I personally think we might even see it go to 5.8 prior to release.

Answer (score 0):

Surely Unity 5.0 will be used by 12.04

Comment: Or at least some 5.x version. There's still three months left before release, so it wouldn't be too surprising if there were one or two upgrades before that.